# Cucumber test in Jenkins running twice

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, cucumber

Test project environment:

- java 17
- junit5
- cucumber7
- maven 3.3.9
- spring
  Runner class:

```
@Suit
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "project.uss.as.play.test")
public class RunnerTest {
}
```

in project I have settings file `junit-platform.properties`:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=false
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=1
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.isolated.read-write=org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ExclusiveResource.GLOBAL_KEY
cucumber.plugin=pretty, html:target/cucumber.html, json:target/cucumber.json, io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm
cucumber.publish.quiet=true
```

in jenkins tests launch for maven:

```
mvn -s /u01/jenkins_slave/workspace/MyTest/.m2/settings.xml clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dcucumber.features=classpath:project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature -Dcucumber.filter.tags="not @skip"
```

As a result in log's I have to test's runs. It's not duplicate. This is two unique test's runs.
I suspect, that it bounded with launch first test for junit and second test for cucumber.
How fix it?

I try add to maven comand:
`-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber`
and
`-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@1` - I annotated case "@1"
not changes

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-Dcucumber.features=....`. As the warning printed in the output explains, this will cause Cucumber to ignore any test selectors from JUnit.

You are also using Surefire, it will ask the `cucumber` engine to look for tests in classes. Cucumber not using classes would normally not find any. But `cucumber.features` was used so now it does.

Then you are also using the `@Suite` annotation to run tests using the `junit-platform-suite` engine. Surefire will also ask this engine to find tests in classes and it will find the  `@Suite` annotated classes. This then delegates to Cucumber which will promptly ignore any of its requests because `cucumber.features` was used.

So now we gave two executions of Cucumber.

The solution is to make Surefire ignore the suite engine and only run Cucumber by adding `-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber`.

So:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber --Dcucumber.features=path/to/example.feature:10
```

Comment: I tried run it like this: `mvn -s ${mvnSettingsPath} clean test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dcucumber.features=${classpath_features} -Dcucumber.filter.tags=\"not @skip\"`.
And it didn't work to me.

Comment: That sounds like a different problemm. But it is hard to tell because you have added a bunch of things. Try and make your problems small. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I add to my old maven script command: '-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber'.
There is no difference. I want to clarify:
"So now we gave two executions of Cucumber".
first: make Surefire ignore the suite engine
second: adding `-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber`.
Did I understand correctly, that `-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber` it's a half of solution my problem? Or it's solution for make "Surefire ignore the suite engine" too?

Comment: No. The semantics are such that only the included engines are executed. All others are excluded. Surefire is just passing these commands onto JUnit so see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.launcher/org/junit/platform/launcher/EngineFilter.html#includeEngines(java.lang.String...)

Comment: You do need to have a version of Surefire that supports `surefire.includeJUnit5Engines` but that goes without saying ofc.

Comment: I understood correctly that all I need to do to solve the problem is add the command: `-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber`.
And need to have a version of Surefire that supports this?

Comment: Well. Without going through the motions of actually making an MCVE, that would be impossible to say. But it is the most likely answer. For anything else, you'll have to debug it yourself.

Comment: Understand. I tried add '-Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber', it's don't work. Now I'm looking for version Surefire that supports 'surefire.includeJUnit5Engines'.
May be reason in version surefire plugin (my 2.22.2). Surefire plugin configuration in .POM could be the reason in problem?

Comment: Yeah. The property is since 3.0.0-M6. https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includeJUnit5Engines

Comment: Oh, I read "MOVE", but you wright "MCVE", what is it "MCVE"? Sorry, my english veeeeery bad.

Comment: It is explained in the url in my first comment in the discussion.

Comment: I'm understand. 3.0.0-M6 didn't help me too. Ok, I will continue to search inside the project. Thank you for your hard work. If I find answer, I wright it there.

Comment: I add 3.0.0-M9 version surefire and launch test local from maven:
- with "include": `mvn clean test -Dsurefire.includeJUnit5Engines=cucumber  -Dcucumber.features=classpath:tests/smoke.feature`
 test run **1 time**, but in result: **0 tests run**. 
- without "include": ```mvn clean test -Dcucumber.features=classpath:tests/smoke.feature```
 test run **2 times**, and in result: **2 tests run**.
 I think, that reason 0 tests run - run test in cucumber, but report from junit.

Comment: Oh. That's interesting.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/2832